# Laravel 5.4 pretty url

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url, laravel-5, pretty-urls

Is that any ways to change the url such `http://localhost:8080/myproject/advertisements` to `http://localhost:8080/myproject/admin/advertisements` always for every URL. I hide the /public and move the .htaccess to root project.

Comment: "I hide the /public and move the .htaccess to root project." You should not be moving the `.htaccess`. You should be pointing your webserver's document root at the `public/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Add a prefix to your route.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups

Scroll down a bit to the `Route Prefixes` section